# Does tensorflow lite support on device training at now

Tags: tensorflow-lite

Because Google issued several paper on federated learning on mobile device, like Gboard, but I can not find docs on training on TFLite website, does TFLite support on device training at now?

Comment: As for today(25 May 2021), TFLite hasn't yet released the support for comprehensive on-device training(on the roadmap) but offers an on-device model personalization. cf https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/guide#technical_constraints

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We do not support general training (or federated training) on TensorFlow Lite. We however have released a tutorial on doing on-device personalization with TF lite. 
https://blog.tensorflow.org/2019/12/example-on-device-model-personalization.html

It basically goes through the process of exporting subgraphs that do training substeps and evaluation to stage training efforts manually. Personalization is the most practical on-device training mechanism right now, so hopefully this addresses your needed.

We are also working on a more comprehensive training solution that will eventually support things like federated learning and also more easy-to-use workflows.

Comment: hi, does a sample or tutorial for iOS federated learning exists?

Comment: Hey, does TFLite support it now?

Comment: any plans or updates on supporting Federated learning for TfLite?